# Why don't we use earth's magnetic field to desaturate the reaction wheels of satellites?

Tags: angular-momentum, magnetic-moment

While reading about the James Webb Telescope I learned that the sun's radiation pressure exerts a torque on Webb's big sunshield that needs to be countered by reaction wheels. Every once in a while, when the wheels start to spin too fast, they need to be slowed down again using the vehicle's thrusters. But since thruster fuel is limited this can't go on forever. So we either refuel James Webb sometime in the future or it goes out of operation.

I then thought about how to get rid of this excess in angular momentum without using fuel and thought about magnetic fields. Lets take a near earth satellite (so the following would obviously not apply to James Webb). The strength of earths magnetic field at its elevation would be approximately $B= 3.5\cdot10^{-5}$ Tesla. If it was equipped with an electro magnet with a magnetic dipole moment of $\mu = 50000$ A$\cdot m^2$ that would correspont to a potential energy of $-\mu \cdot B=1.75$ Joules. I checked online and some rather small satellite reaction wheels have an angular momentum storage of $L=2.5\cdot10^{-2}$ N$\cdot$m$\cdot$s. This would correspont to a kinetic energy of $\frac{L^2}{2I}= 0.833$ Joules. (With a moment of inertia of: $I=3.75\cdot 10^{-4}$) I know I'm ignoring a lot of things in this calculation but it would still seem as if earth's field was strong enough to slow down the reaction wheels? So why aren't we doing it/why is it impractical?

Comment: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01760720/document#:~:text=While%20reaction%20wheels%20are%20easily,field%2C%20a%20torque%20is%20created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why aren't we doing it/why is it impractical?

Magnetorquers are impractical in larger vehicles due to the roughly r^5 growth in moment of inertia. They are also impractical beyond low Earth orbit due to the inverse cube nature of the intensity of the Earth's magnetic field.

Those impracticality concerns do not cover small satellites in low Earth orbit. There are several small satellites in low Earth orbit that already do what you suggested: They use reaction wheels for attitude control and use magnetorquers for desaturation. In those satellites, the magnetorquers are not used for attitude control; they are only used during desaturation operation. During those desaturation operations, the goal is to have the magnetorquers apply an external torque on the vehicle in a manner that makes the reaction wheel-based attitude control system counteract in a way that moves the reaction wheels away from the saturation limits.